# xsd wellformedness

Tags: xml, xsd

http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/?lang=en&viewSourceCode=1&url=http://45143.com/finance-feed/abc.xml&onlyWellFormed=1

check the url above for validator results.

Line 171 in the XSD is getting truncated... feels like a stream error to me but this cant be happening as both are just rendering text files--no on the fly parsing going on here...

so why is xs-group becoming xs-gr?

please advise...

edit `<latestDividend xsi:nil="true"/>` is getting truncated on line 41 in the xml too... any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking us why the validator website isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same thing as validome.org with Firefox, Chrome and WFetch--that last of which blindly reports the text obtained from the socket similar to curl or wget. Looks like the server responding to http://45143.com/finance-feed/financial2.xsd is actually sending an xsd where line 171 has xs:gr instead of xs:group.